# AWS Data out transfer charges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

A and B Two AWS accounts. What is the Data transfer charges between A account mumbai region Ec2 instance to B Account Mumbai region(Same region and Different Account) and A Account Mumbai region Ec2 instance to B account US region(Different region and different account)..?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad in nature. your data size decide how you will be charged

Q. If I have two instances in different availability zones, how will I be charged for regional data transfer?

Each instance is charged for its data in and data out. Therefore, if data is transferred between these two instances, it is charged out for the first instance and in for the second instance.

Q. If I have two instances in different regions, how will I be charged for data transfer?

Each instance is charged for its data in and data out at Internet Data Transfer rates. Therefore, if data is transferred between these two instances, it is charged at Internet Data Transfer Out for the first instance and at Internet Data Transfer In for the second instance.

AWS faq
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#Billing

Comment: If my corporate system connected to aws vpc using Direct connect so now Is my corporate server charged for data transfer out..? if yes,   what type of charges applying for my corporate server out ..?  regional or internet rate..?

Comment: first  3 questions will answer your query 
https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/faqs/#Billing

https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/pricing/